# Equations containing outer products of vectors

Tags: python, c++, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

[image]

where x is a column vector. 
We know from the diagonal elements in A, the value of x entries. But signs of them remains unknown. For example:

```
import numpy as np
A = array([[ 1.562, -0.833, -0.833, -0.031, -0.031,  0.167],
   [-0.833,  0.795,  0.167, -0.149,  0.167, -0.146],
   [-0.833,  0.167,  0.795,  0.167, -0.149, -0.146],
   [-0.031, -0.149,  0.167,  1.68 , -0.833, -0.833],
   [-0.031,  0.167, -0.149, -0.833,  1.68 , -0.833],
   [ 0.167, -0.146, -0.146, -0.833, -0.833,  1.792]])
np.sqrt(A.diagonal())
>>> array([ 1.24979998,  0.89162773,  0.89162773,  1.29614814,  1.29614814,
    1.33865604])
```

But we still dont know the signs. With a mask we have the product signs:

```
A > 0
>>> array([[ True, False, False, False, False,  True],
   [False,  True,  True, False,  True, False],
   [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
   [False, False,  True,  True, False, False],
   [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
   [ True, False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

How can I find x elements signs.

Comment: By the way: This is also called [Dyadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) or [Outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product).

Comment: I edited the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that (-x)(-x)^T = (x)(x)^T, so you can't distinguish x from -x.  Given that, you can determine the sign pattern (i.e. you can determine whether two elements have the same or opposite signs).  In fact, since each row of A is a scalar multiple of x, each row gives you the sign pattern (unless the row is all 0, which is possible if an element of x is 0).  The same holds for the columns.

Note that your example A can not be a product of the form (x)(x)^T.  It has full rank.  The maximum possible rank of (x)(x)^T is 1.

For example,

```
In [14]: x = np.array([1.0, -2.0, -3.0, 4.0])

In [15]: np.outer(x, x)
Out[15]: 
array([[  1.,  -2.,  -3.,   4.],
       [ -2.,   4.,   6.,  -8.],
       [ -3.,   6.,   9., -12.],
       [  4.,  -8., -12.,  16.]])
```

Note the sign pattern in the product.  Each row (and each column) is either (+, -, -, +) or (-, +, +, -).

Comment: I am not sure about your last line, could you explain more?

Comment: Which was my last line when you wrote that comment?

Answer (score 0):

In general, **you can't**.

For example, imagine the matrix `A == [1]`. 
How should anyone know whether `x` is `[1]` or `[-1]`?

Comment: I am looking for all combinations of answers. In your example there are two combinations which are OK.